# Juno for Julia: Autocompletion using a key or do I have to use the mouse?

Tags: julia

I am trying to use autocomplete in Juno. Is there a key to use the suggestion or do I always have to use the mouse?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Tab works for me. Does it not work for you?

Comment: Tab works great! Simply could not find it... enter, space, shift+space, etc ... it all seemed to be more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note that what we talked about here is the former [light-table](http://lighttable.com)-based Juno, not the Atom-based one.**

the default setting of "auto-complete" in your `default.keymap` file should be:

```
[:editor.keys.normal "tab" :auto-complete]
```

you can checkout it by

Step1: open juno's commands window or pressing `Ctrl+space`

Step2: search `settings` and you will find a list:

```
Settings: User script
Settings: User keymap
...
Settings: Default keymap
...
```

Step3: click `Settings: Default keymap` and search for 'auto-complete'

if you want to map another key for 'auto-complete', you can customize it in `user.keymap`.